# MACD Strategy in Backtesting.py

Tags: python, back-testing

Good afternoon, can anyone tell my why the following strategy is not generating signals? The RSI part works fine but I have problems with the MACD. I tried the logic on a normal data frame, it worked there and I think it has something to do with the `backtesting.py` library.

```
import ta
import pandas as pd
from backtesting import Backtest, Strategy
from backtesting.lib import crossover

class MACD_RSIStrategy(Strategy):
    def init(self):
        close = pd.Series(self.data.Close)
        rsi_indicator = ta.momentum.RSIIndicator(close, window=14)
        macd_indicator = ta.trend.MACD(close, 26, 12, 9, False)
        self.macd = macd_indicator.macd()
        self.signal = macd_indicator.macd_signal()
        self.rsi = self.I(rsi_indicator.rsi)
        self.macd = self.I(macd_indicator.macd)

    def next(self):
        if crossover(self.macd, self.signal) and self.rsi[-1] < 30:
            self.position.close()
            self.buy()
        elif crossover(self.signal, self.macd) and self.rsi[-1] > 70:
            self.position.close()
            self.sell()
```